# How to use Swagger / OpenAPI to make API testing easier?

Tags: testing, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger for documenting my API. Now I want to write python test for end to end testing of the API. How will swagger.yaml file help me in this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate Python API client, which comes with test files.

Here are some examples of test files auto-generated by Swagger Codegen

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/python/test

Then you can update the test files with the actual tests you want to conduct.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger / OpenAPI itself can be directly leveraged as tests with many of the tools listed [here](https://openapi.tools/#testing) to generate requests and then verify responses.

If you are looking for examples in Python, here is a [sample project](https://github.com/znsio/specmatic-order-api-python) (Not an end to end test as dependencies are stubbed out, however it should still serve as a relevant reference) that leverages [Specmatic](https://specmatic.in/) (Disclosure - I am CTO at Specmatic).